# How do different $|\text{Alive}\rangle+|\text{Dead}\rangle$ kind of states behave under decoherence?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, superposition, decoherence, noise, schroedingers-cat

I am looking for literature that investigates said behaviour for spins. So far I found many papers on how to measure the macroscopicity of states and therefore a classification of macroscopic states. By this I found out that there are some prototypical states, foremost the GHZ-state, that could be investigated. Although I am intersted in the behaviour under decoherence itself - which obviously must depend on the prototype of state in consideration or several parameters that come with it - but I cannot find any proper literature. Is this a field of research interest that isn't there yet? At least in quantum information I thought I would find something similar...

Comment: I think the term you want for your titular states is spin superpositions. But $S^2,\,S_z$ are simultaneously good quantum numbers.

Comment: The title of your question does not seem to relate to the body very well.  It seems like you're asking for resources about systems showing [GHZ State](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenberger%E2%80%93Horne%E2%80%93Zeilinger_state).  The question might be tagged with resource-request if that's the case.